# Is there a good description to enable https for ejabberd?

Tags: ssl, ejabberd, lets-encrypt

I have installed ejabberd on a vm and i successfully made accounts and accessed the admin panel. I have tried to get https enabled via lets encrypt but i havent managed to get it running. After checking the docs, google as well as the forum here i still didnt find a useful description to get this done.

thanks in advance for any further information on that note.

Answer (score 0):

There are a pair of paragraphs regarding Let’s Encrypt SSL certificates in this tutorial: https://www.process-one.net/blog/how-to-move-the-office-to-real-time-im-on-ejabberd/

Once you have setup the certificates, you can enable the tls option in several listeners, like ejabberd_c2s, and probably you want to enable in ejabberd_http too. See the first example here, concretely the configuration of port 5281:
https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/listen/#examples